# Translation Request from French - Comparison of the reals of a topos smooth structures on an elementary topos

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, topos-theory, translation-request, mathematical-french

I've been reading on Real numbers objects in a Topos, and I want to read this [article](http://archive.numdam.org/article/CTGDC_1975__16_3_217_0.pdf) (starting page 22 on the attached PDF) the nlab references.

The problem is that I don't read French, and I haven't been able to find a translation in English.

Does anyone have a copy of this translation that they might be able to reupload elsewhere or send to me?

Thank you.

Comment: As a French native speaker I can work on a translation but it would take me time. Do you have a tight deadline to use the English translation?

Comment: @SylvainJulien No deadline for the translation, mainly for enrichment. Thank you so much.

Comment: Ok. I will do my best to provide a clear and faithful translation. You can contact me at sylvainjul'at'gmail'dot'com.